# How to find line break in text file using Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to load text file in spark, I am getting error like

```
Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 31 fields are required while 1 values are provided.
```

the file size is 20GB. Manually its not possible to check line by line. What is the best option to find the line break and to load the file? I am using pyspark to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a fast check with pySpark.

Try to load your file like this:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('filePath').map(lambda x: x.split('<yourSeparator>'))
rdd.map(lambda x: len(x)).zipWithIndex().sortByKey().take(5)
```

this will return the index of the Column lenght and the index of it (started with 0)

Comment: I am using Split for column delimiter,

Data like below:-

1#|#xyz#|#2500
2#|#abc#|#1500

rdd = sc.textFile('filePath').map(lambda x: x.split('#|#'))

It not able to handle Line break or row delimiter.

Comment: What do you mean that you are not able to handle line break? The file hasn't line breaks?

Comment: I am using SPLIT() function for column delimiter,column delimiter is #|# ,  Now I need to remove line breaks too. How can I do this? kindly   guide me.

Comment: Well, if you don't need line breaks, why don't you try `flatMap` function?

Comment: AccountHeaderData = Accountheaderfile.map(lambda s: s.split("#|#")).filter(lambda s: s[0] != "First Column")
AccountHeaderDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(AccountHeaderData,AccountheaderSchema)
AccountHeaderDF.write.saveAsTable("Table")



In the above Code, Where can I use faltmap to remove line break?  File has line break, if I opened the file in Ultraedit and copy the data and paste to notepad.the line break issue wont coming on the file.